# How to check if user does not have particular role in bbpress?

Tags: php, bbpress

I have function that checks if user has more than 15 posts on forum, but I want also to implement that this user must not havve role "BLOCKED".

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id()  ;
$topic_count  = bbp_get_user_topic_count_raw( $user_id);
$reply_count = bbp_get_user_reply_count_raw( $user_id);
$post_count   = (int) $topic_count + $reply_count;      
if ($post_count > 15) { 
//show here
}
```

Now, what I want is:
*If user has no BLOCKED role and has more than 15 posts show them this.*
I can't find way to do this, so anyone knows the function and how to apply it on my code?

Comment: See https://github.com/tareq1988/bbpress-block-user for a plugin that blocks users.

Comment: I don't need that, my function is for another purpose.

Comment: Why don't you use  __bbp_get_user_role($user_id)__ ?